# HybridAuth validate login

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, hybridauth

As you know users can go to their Facebook account > APPS and remove applications from accessing their account. 
The same thing can happen in other login providers (such as Google or Twitter).

Here is a screenshot of Facebook APPs list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMTCA.png

Is there an easy and global way to find out, when a user removes APP access (e.g. log off their account in our website)

Comment: Facebook lets you specify a “Deauthorize Callback URL” for that purpose; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#deauth-callback // How the other ones are handling this and whether they provide something similar, I don’t know – check their docs.